# How to convert hex to varchar and vice-versa using Sybase ASE?

Tags: sql, hex, sap-ase

Is it possible to convert varchar to hex and vice-versa using Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sybase.public.ase.general/S8b1AVDQWlQ

Comment: It's never too late to improve your answer.